# Rails 4 application asks to sign up everytime a user authenticates with omniauth and github

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

I have a rails application that have devise as authentication backend. I am learning to implement omniauth in a bigger application that I am developing and I decided to first check it using small app. So, my app have one user model. Two controllers(one for static home page another for overriding devise omniauth callback)

I have no problem to sign in with facebook but I am having problem with github signin. Github is asking to sign up again and again.

https://github.com/bishisht/omniauth-rails-learning

Above is the link to github repo.

**omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
   def facebook
     # raise request.env['omniauth.auth']
     # # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
     @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

     if @user.persisted?
       sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
       set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
     else
       session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
       redirect_to new_user_registration_url
     end
   end

  def github

    # raise request.env['omniauth.auth']
    # # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Github") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.github_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :omniauthable

   def self.from_omniauth(auth)
     where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
       user.email = auth.info.email
       user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
       user.full_name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
     end
   end         
 end
```

EDIT:
response of

```
puts request.env['omniauth.auth'].to_yaml


--- !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
provider: github
uid: '366217'
info: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash
  nickname: bishisht
  email: 
  name: Bishisht Bhatta
  image: https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/366217?v=3
  urls: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
    GitHub: https://github.com/bishisht
    Blog: http://bishisht.github.io/
credentials: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
  token: 012d594abc447bb4ce95c07244f946f206d425f7
  expires: false
extra: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
  raw_info: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
    login: bishisht
    id: 366217
    avatar_url: https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/366217?v=3
    gravatar_id: ''
    url: https://api.github.com/users/bishisht
    html_url: https://github.com/bishisht
    followers_url: https://api.github.com/users/bishisht/followers
    following_url: https://api.github.com/users/bishisht/following{/other_user}
    gists_url: https://api.github.com/users/bishisht/gists{/gist_id}
    starred_url: https://api.github.com/users/bishisht/starred{/owner}{/repo}
    subscriptions_url: https://api.github.com/users/bishisht/subscriptions
    organizations_url: https://api.github.com/users/bishisht/orgs
    repos_url: https://api.github.com/users/bishisht/repos
    events_url: https://api.github.com/users/bishisht/events{/privacy}
    received_events_url: https://api.github.com/users/bishisht/received_events
    type: User
    site_admin: false
    name: Bishisht Bhatta
    company: Narmada Infosys
    blog: http://bishisht.github.io/
    location: Netizen
    email: bishisht.np.mnr@gmail.com
    hireable: true
    bio: 
    public_repos: 59
    public_gists: 4
    followers: 21
    following: 98
    created_at: '2010-08-16T17:42:52Z'
    updated_at: '2016-06-17T17:49:23Z'
    private_gists: 0
    total_private_repos: 0
    owned_private_repos: 0
    disk_usage: 167968
    collaborators: 0
    plan: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
      name: free
      space: 976562499
      collaborators: 0
      private_repos: 0
  all_emails: []
```

Comment: can you post the response (i.e. request.env["omniauth.auth"]) from github?

Comment: I have updated the question as per your response. what do you suggest now?